# How to enable TCP sockets to work over the internet

Tags: sockets, tcp, firewall

I work in a team that supports mature C++ components that communicate using TCP sockets on Windows. On a LAN this is fine but we want to move the server to the internet and host this for our customers. This isn't a traditional client-server setup because the server can initiate communication. I understand that network administratators would be unlikely to agree to allow a server on the public internet to call into a client behind a firewall so some redevelopment is needed. There seem to be all sorts of ways of proceeding but having little knowledge of comms I find it difficult to decide what options are worth researching. Is there an obviously best way to go?

C# is favoured for new new devellopment over C++.

Comment: It depends on it, are your customers ok with adding an entry in their firewall to allow your server to communicate with them directly ? Is this at all possible because your customer can have multiple local IP addresses and just one public IP address. The server would then, when it takes initiative only be able to talk to one host. The problem here is NAT/PAT.

Comment: In short, you should refactor the application so that the initiative is always from the client that is running behind a firewall and never from the server. That way your customers don't have to rearrange their firewall.